# How to set redux state variable to component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, setstate, mapstatetoprops

I have the below component

```
export class Requirements extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    locArray: PropTypes.array
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedJ: props.locArray.length !== 0 ? '1' : '2'
    };
    this.updateSelected = this.updateSelected.bind(this);
  }

  updateSelected(e, selectedJ) {
    this.setState({ selectedJ }, () => {
      console.log('this.state.selectedJ:', this.state.selectedJ);
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
     // CODE
              <Field
                onChange={this.updateSelected}
              />
            <DocTable
              selectedJ={this.state.selectedJ}
            />
    );
  }
}
```

Im mapping the locArray from the redux state to the component props like below

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  locArray:
    state.role.roleArray?.[props.index].roleData?.rolelocArray || []
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Requirements);
```

so that i can initialize the state variable selectedJ based on locArray length like below

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedJ: props.locArray.length !== 0 ? '1' : '2'
    };
    this.updateSelected = this.updateSelected.bind(this);
  }
```

I feel something is wrong with this approach. I get the below error on the code that's inside the render because of this locArray that i mapped in the mapStateToProps.

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

my code works as expected without the locArray in the mapStateToProps but i need to get that from redux store and initialize the state variable selectedJ based on this locArray.

Fairly new to redux, Any thoughts on how to achieve this would help. Thanks

Comment: Don't see anything in the code that would cause your error. Is there more code in the render method you're not showing here possibly?

Comment: I could actually fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

Issue was with reading rolelocArray from redux state in mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  locArray:
    state.role.roleArray?.[props.index].roleData?.rolelocArray || []
});
```

rolelocArray was not always available. It was being set on a condition in the reducer. I thought my || [] would work if rolelocArray is not available at any point in time.

But it didn't.

Instead, I was reading from another variable "rolelocRefArray" that's available available in the redux state.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  locArray:
    state.role.roleArray?.[props.index].roleData?.rolelocRefArray || []
});
```

Another way of solving this could be having initial value for rolelocArray in the redux state.